# Recreating Curl -F with Invoke-WebRequest -InFile

Tags: powershell, curl

I am trying to post a file to an api using powershell. I am able to post to the api with curl -F   but not with Invoke-WebRequest ...-infile . I get an internal server error. I am assuming that it has something to do with how the file is broken up but I am not sure.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'myapi' -ContentType 'multipart/form-data' -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $Fields
```

Where:

```
$headers = @{'Authorization' : 'Basic <Token>'}
```

Error:

```
 Invoke-RestMethod : 
500 Internal Server Error
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.
```

Comment: The authentication is definitely working.

Comment: For anyone who has similar problems in the future: https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/396726/PowerShell-V3-Multipart-formdata-example